# Why when the angle between AM and BM is k*pi then the group of points is the line (AB) - [A,B]?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, group-theory, complex-numbers

I'm sorry for my broken English(I don't know much Math vocabulary in English)

This is all on the complex plane, just to say.

My question is:

When arg(AM/BM) = k*pi

Then it means the group of points is the line (AB) except the two points A and B? I don't get it.

Comment: Your English seems fine. Please define $M$ though. [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: @Shaun Thanks. Can you answer the question please if you know?

Comment: You're welcome. I don't understand exactly what the question is asking, I'm afraid. I'd have answered it by now otherwise.

Comment: @Shaun It's okay. I don't think anyone will answer it anyway since it's probably the wording was very strange for anyone to understand.

Comment: @TechnoKnight Hey maybe give us some context will help the next guy that clicks on this thread! :)